# Cannot click on tkinter button more than twice

Tags: python, button, tkinter

I am a newbie to tkinter and have know idea what I am doing sometimes:D . I created a python script to get Corona Virus Stats from a GitHub post [link](https://rb.gy/7jct1u) The script has over 20 files in it so I thought I should just create one file to run all the other files. So what other better way to do it than creating a UI. And that's what I did I used tkinter to run all the files. If they clicked on x button then I would run abc. And I ended up running these files by importing them in a certain order(Don't know If that was the best way). So here is where I ran into an error. I don't exactly know if this error is because of how I imported my files or my tkinter code is just wrong. I just couldn't seem to click on a button twice. I would run my program and click on a button, it would run properly and then the next time I clicked on that same button It would just not work. There was no error and no output. Nothing would happen. Here is my code:

```
#Import tkinter
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import simpledialog
tk = tk.Tk()
Max = 190
def RunDeaths():
    #If they click on RunDeaths I will run this function
    #Check if they have already entered a path
    try:
        open('/Users/test/Documents/python/Py_Programs/Hackathon/DeathStats/Info.txt','r')
        from DeathStats import RunAll
    except:
        YourPath = simpledialog.askstring('Countries','''Please Enter Your Path To HACKATHON Folder:
    Example: 
    \"/Users/Name/Documents/python/\" 
    Note: Leave out the HACKATHON folder and you must put a slash at the end''',parent=tk)
    #Write this path to a file call Info.txt
        file = open('/Users/test/Documents/python/Py_Programs/Hackathon/DeathStats/Info.txt','w')
        file.write(str(YourPath)+'\n')
        file.write(str(Max))
        file.close()
        #Run all the files that gather the data for Corona Virus Deaths
        from DeathStats import RunAll
def RunRecoveredCases():
    #If they click on RecoveredCases Run this
    #Check If they had already entered a path
    try:
        open('/Users/test/Documents/python/Py_Programs/Hackathon/RecoveredCases/Info.txt','r')
        from RecoveredCases import RunAll
    except:
        YourPath = simpledialog.askstring('Countries','''Please Enter Your Path To HACKATHON Folder:
    Example: 
    \"/Users/Name/Documents/python/\" 
    Note: Leave out the HACKATHON folder and you must put a slash at the end''',parent=tk)
        file = open('/Users/test/Documents/python/Py_Programs/Hackathon/RecoveredCases/Info.txt','w')
        #Write there path to a file
        file.write(str(YourPath)+'\n')
        file.write(str(Max))
        file.close()
        #Run all the files that gather all the Recovered Cases
        from RecoveredCases import RunAll
#* * Here is where I think I went wrong But Im not sure
Deaths = Button(tk,height = 20, width = 30, text='Run Deaths',command = RunDeaths,highlightbackground='#000000')
Recovered = Button(tk,height = 20, width = 30, text='Run Recovered Cases',command = RunRecoveredCases,highlightbackground='#000000')
Deaths.pack()
Recovered.pack()
tk.mainloop()
```

So my question and problem is: Why can I not click on a button more than twice?
This has happened to me before and I could not fix it. Any help would be appreciated.(If you would like to run my program because my explanation was just not good enough here is a git hub repo [GitHub](https://github.com/BuddyBob/Py_Programs/tree/master/Hackathon))
Thank You

Comment: `from DeathStats import RunAll`  Imports only run the first time even if you import again. Do the import at the top of the code then run a function in the module at each button click.

Comment: It is because module will be import once when using `import` statement.  So first time you click the button, the function get executed and import the module.  However if the button is clicked again, the function still get executed but the module will not be imported again as it is already imported.

Comment: @Mike67 So In RunAll create a function that run the code if a button was clicked in the main file? Do you mind showing this in code. Thank you!

Comment: keep all your imports to the top of the code and try?

Comment: @AirStalk3r You should always do all your imports at the top. Its good for being organized and helps prevent any errors for things that get called out of order as your code grows and becomes more complex.

Comment: Your button is being clicked twice but there is no effect because there is nothing much to do, you are just importing a module, so if you try something below it like, `print('Hello')`, you will see that the button works :D

Comment: Well if I import the modules at the top wouldn't it run the files without the user asking it to do so. The user must give some info before the modules are run.

Comment: no? just importing the module wont do any harm unless you call the modules?

Comment: Ok haha I see, there is a misunderstanding, I am importing my files not modules, so when importing a file it runs automatically. You don't have to call it. So If I import my files at the top of a script they will run first.

Comment: oh okay? im assuming that this `RunAll` is a function?

Comment: Nope, RunAll is a file that imports other files. There is no function in RunAll.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you are assuming that `from RecoveredCases import RunAll` will run the code in `RecoveredCases.py` each time it is imported. That is a false assumption. Python caches code that is imported.

The proper way to use code in a separate file is to put the code in a function or class, import the function or class exactly once, and then call the function or instantiate the class whenever you want to run the code.

Comment: Haha you were correct! I just had to put my RunAll into a function and call that function from my main file and whala! Thank you!!